# Android: Pressing a button in a listview item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter

I have a custom listview adapter which contains two buttons, the problem is it's hard to click on the button and it keeps losing focus, or you have to touch it multiple times before it recognizes the click.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

    DataEntity data = entityList.get(position);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_mission_row, parent, false);

// inflate other views


    Button playButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_button);
    playButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    MyClickListener listener = new MyClickListener(context,entity);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
    playButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonMap);
    playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_button);
    playButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: It should recognize the click, the click response is based on what you are doing in your onClick() method. If you are loading plenty of things then you will be feel like click event is too late to respond. Otherwise your background source might be small not fully covered the button surface...

Comment: it didn't even change the pressed state drawable, that's why I ruled out my click listener from the equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code once. You have not created a different button object for `buttonmap`.

```
playButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonMap);
```

Here you are using the same button object as you have created for `buttonPlay`

Also when your are populating the ListView then you should use the [ViewHolder pattern](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_hoder) to populate the listview efficiently.

Comment: yes, it seems like the views contained in my rows where insync, the ViewHolder pattern fixed it, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

See below one.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            imageLoader = new SISIImageLoader(MY_ACTIVITY.this);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.game_display_row, null);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.deleteGameBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteGameBtn);


            v.setTag(holder);
        }

        final Gamedata o = items.get(position);

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();


        if (o != null) {

            Button deleteGameBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteGameBtn);

            holder.deleteGameBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                        // do what you want to do on click 

                    }


            });

        }
        return v;
    }
```

Hope it will solve your problem.